# Когда работает ядро?

Tags: ядро

Предположим, у нас один процессор.
Вопрос, возможно, смешной: исполняется 1 процесс, переключился контекст на следующий - исполняются инструкции следующего... А когда, собственно, само ядро работает, когда сетевой стек, например, прерывания от сетевой карты обрабатывает, если постоянно исполняется код процессов?

Comment: Может есть отдельный процесс для этого? :D

Comment: ядро чего? Процессора?

Comment: @Эникейщик операционной системы

Comment: @ВадимАлександру ну как-то странно, пользовательских процессов в 100 раз больше - выходит ядро работает очень редко

Comment: @xperious и вы думаете все работают с одинаковым приоритетом?

Comment: @ВадимАлександру я не знаю, я поэтому и спрашиваю

Comment: так а кто по-вашему переключает процессор между процессорами? Дух билла джобса торвальдса?

Comment: «переключился контекст на следующий» — нет, переключение идёт в ядро, а там дальше ядро уже работает и выбирает, какой процесс исполнить следующим. Ну а прерывания потому и называются прерываниями, что они прерывают работу (в данном случае текущего процесса) и запускают выполнение обработчика прерывания в ядре. Кстати, переключение между процессами тоже реализовано через прерывание, поступающее от аппаратного таймера

Comment: Касательно «ядро работает очень редко» — да, оно и правда работает очень редко. Я тут глянул метрики одного своего сервера, обрабатывающего видеопоток с IP-камеры — 30% времени работали процессы, 6% времени работало ядро и всякий ввод-вывод, остальные 64% процессор проставивал

Comment: Когда программа   выполняет системный вызов (инструкции исполняются в привелигированном режиме), то как считать -- работает ядро и пользовательский процесс? Понятно, что есть чистое время ядра, это обработка прерываний (тут же "верхняя часть" диспетчера), процессы ядра, занимающиеся структурами памяти и sync вывода на диски